# i want to use if condition in a flutter widget function to save the data in the text field like mail or password in flutter

Tags: flutter, if-statement

```
Widget buildtextfield(
    IconData icon, String hintText, bool password, bool email) {
        switch()
return Padding(

    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 8.0),
    child: TextField(
              if(password){
             //  error expected an identifier
                   onChanged: (value) => setState(() => this.password = value),
                   onSubmitted: (value) => setState(() => this.password = value),
              }

        textInputAction: TextInputAction.done,
        obscureText: password,
        keyboardType: email ? TextInputType.emailAddress : TextInputType.text,

        decoration: InputDecoration(
            prefixIcon: Icon(icon),
            enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
              borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey),
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(35.0)),
            ),
            focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
              borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey),
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(35.0)),
            ),
            contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
            hintText: hintText,
            hintStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 14, color: Colors.grey))),
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this

```
TextField(
      onChanged: (value) {
        if (password) setState(() => this.password = value);
      },
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Points to note:

- You do not need to call `setState` when updating email or password for most cases.
- You can use the `validator` which is available in `TextFormField` to apply any conditional statements. The validator won't allow email or password value to be set until the `validator` function returns `null`.

#### Reference Code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class LoginForm extends StatefulWidget {
  LoginFormState createState() => LoginFormState();
}

class LoginFormState extends State<LoginForm> {
  String email;
  String password;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(children: <Widget>[
      TextFormField(
        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
        keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
        onChanged: (String value) => email = value,
        decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: 'Email'),
        validator: (v) {
          if (v.isEmpty) return 'Please provide an email address.';
          return null; // returning 'null' will allow value to be saved in email.
        },
      ),
      TextFormField(
        obscureText: true,
        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
        onChanged: (String value) => password = value,
        decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: 'Password'),
        validator: (v) {
          if (v.trim().isEmpty) return 'Please provide a password.';
          return null; // returning 'null' will allow value to be saved in password.
        },
      ),
    ]);
  }
}
```